# On a US keyboard why is + shifted but - isn't?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am wondering why standard US keyboards allow you to type <kbd>-</kbd> by simply hitting the key, but the <kbd>+</kbd> button right next to it needs the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. The default for that key is <kbd>=</kbd> and not a minus symbol. + and - are similar operations, which has led me to wonder why they are reversed in their dependence on shift. Is there any reason I am not thinking of which would have lead to this choice?

Comment: On a [german keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout), `+` and `-`  both don't need the shift key.

Comment: @Uooo Same for italian keyboards.

Comment: Also on Danish keyboard, which I consider to be the standard keyboard, + and - do not need shift.

Comment: + for noticing it. I am keyboard from several years and I never noticed this

Comment: on Japanese keyboard common keys such as `'`, `"` require a shift but `@`, `:` aren't although they're not used very frequently. And `'`, `"` are even moved to the number row, with `"` at the `2` button, so it's not easy to type English quickly. `=`, which is very frequently used when programming, also requires shift, makes it a pain for programmer.

Comment: on Czech keyboard, you have `+` on the key `1` and you don't need shift for that. You don't need shift for `-` either :) Needed to say, keyboard switch shortcut is my friend.

Comment: As a programmer, I like to think that it's for typing `+=` on the same key. :D

Comment: @PrinceTyke That is a handy feature, but you could just as easily do it by hitting shift second instead of first.

Comment: @Keavon I do agree, but I think that it's easier to start a token (for lack of a better word) holding shift and then releasing it, just as we type words beginning with a capital letter. Then again, it could just be that I'm used to typing the `+=` token. Of course, I'm just being silly up here in the comments.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Well, you are, obviously, talking about the section of the keyboard whose main function is to write letters for words and sentences, because on the right side of the keyboard, both signs can be used without the shift key.

Going back to your question, the difference is related to the different uses that the dash symbol has on normal writing and the lack of use of the plus sign on the same circumstances.

You can read more about that on the [dash page on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash).

Comment: That makes sense, but an = sign isn't used in writing either, so why would they not make = require shift and + the default?

Comment: Because spamming ='s makes a more prominent horizontal rule than spamming +'s?

Comment: You could argue that "=" sign is used more frequently than "+" in programming. And, as suggested by Nate Kerkhofs, perhaps first keyboards were optimised for software development.

Comment: I think this does not answer the question. If so, why are there different keyboard layouts? `+` and `-` don't require the shift key on a QUERTZ layout, yet the German language do not need more `+` signs in a letter than English. @jfrej On a german keyboard you need the Shift key for `=`, so the programming argument does not make much sense for me. If keyboards were optimised for programming, they would be the same everywhere, independent on the locale.

Comment: Ok, the question is not specific enough. It asks about "standard keyboards" but it's quite clear it's about the US standard keyboard (QWERTY) as that's the layout where "=" doesn't require Shift.

Comment: German keyboard layout is much more complicated to allow a greater set of characters. In fact, QWERTZ was the standard layout for Polish keyboards which has now been mostly replaced with QWERTY based so called ["Polish programmer's keyboard"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#Polish). Still, it's all just a comment, "could argue" and "perhaps".

Comment: +1 for the number pad.  It was my first thought the second I read the title.

Answer (score 11):

The early typewriters were actually setup differently: the Remington no 2 had an entirely different layout:

[image: Remington no2, 1878]

The earliest typewriter with the <kbd>+</kbd> on <kbd>shift-=</kbd> that I could find was the IBM Model A from 1949 (and maybe the 01 from 1939, but I cannot find a keyboard layout for that). by that time, the first programmable computers were around, which were programmed in assembly. it's possible that there has been some cross-pollination between keyboard layouts and those first programming languages (and the ideas of Von Neumann and other pioneers).

FORTRAN, which is one of the earliest programming languages, was also developed by IBM. It's possible that these early keyboards designed by IBM were optimized for development of programs in the IBM language Fortran. Later creators of keyboards likely used the same layout.

Comment: Do you have any idea what keyboard first had !"#$%&'() on the top row, or "=" as shifted "-", or "<" and ">" as shifted "," and "."?  Or the classic "?" as shifted "/"?  Those correlations are baked into ASCII character set, but I wonder which if any predate it?

Comment: @supercat Unfortunately, I don't have this information. The tricky bit is that there are no keyboard layout diagrams for many of the older keyboards, so you need to parse Google Images manually for a photo of the relevant typewriter with legible keys. Since there have been dozens, maybe hundreds of typewriters so far, finding the first one to incorporate a specific layout is a huge job.

Comment: Even pictures may not answer the whole question, since some typewriters (like my grandfather's) have some keys which appear to be customizable, though I don't have any alternative keys and type-bars that would swap out.  If nobody's archived typewriter-company catalogs I'm not sure how one could find out what keys were available.

Comment: In theory, someone could make a deal with a typewriter museum and make a list of all the typewriter layouts. But this is getting somewhat off-topic, but if anyone wants to do this, feel free.

Comment: Am I just dense, or does the pictured typewriter have _no_ "+"? (Nor a "1" for that matter!)

Comment: @BrianS: It seems safe to assume that the "1" key has fallen off. Perhaps it carried a shifted "+".

Comment: @kundor I believe the "1" key was omitted on purpose on older keyboards.  Lowercase L or uppercase i would have been indistinguishable from the number 1.

Comment: @supercat Customizable keys and matching typebars were definitely a thing as long as manual typewriters were in common use (probably through the '80s at least).  The biggest markets, I believe, were probably journalists who needed to be able to type foreign place names and academics who could use a single typewriter with a half-dozen accent keys to write in most of the Romance languages.

Comment: @cimmanon Correct about "l" being used in place of "1", and uppercase "O" usually substituted for zero as well--I'm surprised to see it in the picture of the Remington above.

Comment: The typewriter in the picture is a German language typewriter.

Comment: And some of us still remember having to overstrike `.` with `'` on mechanical typewriters to type exclamation point, among other combinations. With computing -- and interchangable-font typewriters, to a lesser degree -- came the need to give these characters their own identity, and their own keys.

Comment: @BenMiller Actually, if you watch carefully, you see that it has an (almost) full support of French as well, the only thing that seems to be missing is `ï`, but it's not so much

Comment: wow that thing was sold as 'portable' I wonder what they'd make of a laptop :-)

Answer (score 6):

On the numeric area of the keyboard, plus does not need a shift key, and neither does / or *. In fact, it often is quite a big key there. So, when focused on entering numeric data, you have all the relevant keys readily available.

[image]

When focused on entering text, the + symbol is not as important as the - symbol, as the - symbol is also used in running text as a punctuation mark. While technically the - is not an hyphen or a dash, it is most often used as such by anyone who is not a professional type setter. You' ll notice that Microsoft Word will often replace the minus with the appropriate symbol as an autocorrect feature.

Comment: The first paragraph and the image are irrelevant, the question is about **why is `+` shifted** and not about **how to type `+`**.

Comment: @A.L The first paragraph negates the premisse in the question that + is shifted at all in the context where + and - are "similar operations".

Answer (score 4):

Computer keyboards are based on typewriters (since you wanted to make typewriters (people) write on your new awesome computer thingy). Which of course moves this question to the typewriter "keyboard" design - but since there were quite a few competing layouts at the same time, it seems that this one won because it simply was the most convenient in practice. PatomaS answer gives some incentives for that.

Also, my keyboard (czech) does have a <kbd>+</kbd> without holding shift - it's where <kbd>1</kbd> is in english layout. Yes, numbers in the alphanumeric part are used through <kbd>Shift</kbd> - why not, you've got the numeric keyboard for when you're writing numbers (which wasn't there on the typewriter) :)

The numeric keyboard is, on the other hand, designed precisely for entering numbers and calculations - there's jobs where you use the numeric keyboard 80%+ of the time.

In fact, some other keys mentioned here are available without <kbd>Shift</kbd> on the czech layout - including <kbd>=</kbd> and, strangely, <kbd>§</kbd>. Even more weird, the umlaut (<kbd>¨</kbd>, as in eg. <kbd>ü</kbd>) is also there. This is probably because the basic czech layout is based on the german qwertz layout.

And of course, the layouts do get better with time. For example, I'm using the `Czech (QWERTY)` layout, which is very handy for programmers, because:

1. I have the usual czech layout, handy for doing czech UI, and I don't have to switch layouts in my mind when switching from programming to eg. chat.
2. I get the english <kbd>Shift</kbd>'d keyboard by holding <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd>, thus having easy access to the other characters commonly used in programming, like <kbd>%</kbd> or even worse, <kbd>[</kbd>, which is missing in the czech layout altogether.

So layouts improve, even if by small steps (you don't want to alienate your users - Dvorak layout suffers from this, because it's completely different, rathen than being an incremental improvement).

Answer (score 1):

Best I could see for which there is alternative and where `=` could be used in "common" language was for tone.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign#Tone_letter

> The equals sign is also used as a grammatical tone letter in the orthographies of Budu in the Congo-Kinshasa, in Krumen, Mwan and Dan in the Ivory Coast.[6][7] The Unicode character used for the tone letter (U+A78A)[8] is different from the mathematical symbol (U+003D).

This still isn't adequate for the keyboard placement phenomena you described.

Sidenote: I cannot unsee this, each time I look there, I'm like WHY.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a standard computer keyboard, move your right-hand over to the [number pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_pad).  Both the plus and minus (also a dash) are available without using the shift key.

If you are writing words with dash in-them the dash is available on the alpha section.

If you are writing (or doing) math 2+3-1 they are both available in the number area.

Comment: Hyphens and dashes are different things.

Comment: @TRiG, yes but the OP is not asking about Hyphens, they are asking about symbols that look like math symbols.  - & -  both look pretty much the same.